# Updating/Migrating Sentry java from 1.7.3 to 5.7.4

Tags: java, maven, sentry

I've been tasked with updating our manual Sentry Java implementation from their legacy SDK v1.7.3 to the newest version 5.7.4.

Sentry's Migration guide seems to be lacking many steps that would need to be included in this migration.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/migration/

You can see here, that only a few changes are listed, but whole packages have been removed, such as io.sentry.event.

So my question is, is there a simpler migration path than manually refactoring everything? Or at least a guide that is more clear?

I'm not very familiar with Sentry so I apologize if I'm incorrect in anything I've stated.

Comment: The guide is pretty clear to me... make sure you start from the bottom and not the top!. The part at the bottom is for the migration from 1.x to 4.x (which I would suggest first), make sure it compiles/works, then pick the next version.

Comment: It's clear, but it doesn't seem to be complete. What packages are deprecated? I followed the guide step by step, and still getting many errors. I can go one by one of course, but I wouldn't say that's a migration, that's complete refactoring. 

You can see here the packages removed between versions:
https://javadoc.io/doc/io.sentry/sentry/3.0.0/index.html
https://javadoc.io/doc/io.sentry/sentry/1.7.30/index.html

If there is no cleaner solution, so be it, was just wondering.

Comment: @M.Deinum I appreciate the help. I was able to get it working by removing the old packages out and refactoring our code. However, that migration document is certainly not comprehensive.

Comment: @user19145957 feel free to create an issue in https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs or even better a PR with missing steps. I'm sorry to hear you had problems, we tried to make the migration guide as complete as possible.